# SQL Server not wanting to convert to int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my problem: I have an e-mail that goes out with messages. I am trying to include this in my e-mail.

```
IF @StoreID > 1 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @message = 'ID' + StoreName 
    FROM
        db.Stores 
    WHERE
        StoreName = StoreID 
        AND StoreID = @StoreID
```

When I execute the code, it finds the correct store, but says that

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'MK' to data type int.

`@StoreID` is an `int` data type that is the same as `StoreID` in `StoreOrders`

I have two tables, `StoreOrders` and `Stores`.

I need to convert the `@StoreID` to the name in `Stores` so that when the e-mail goes out it says "ID: 'MK'" or whatever ID it is. I plan on having over 20 ID's and then we will be adding new ID's as time goes by, so I do not want to case it or hard-code it.

I don't want to convert 'MK' to int. I want to display 'MK' in my email.

Comment: How is "MK" getting into your query?   Is that the value of `@StoreID`?  If not, then the error might be occurring in some part of the code that you aren't showing us.

Comment: `where  StoreName = StoreID` is most likely your problem.. Remove `StoreName = StoreID` and just have `where StoreID = @StoreID`

Comment: What is the purpose of `where StoreName = StoreID`?  That's comparing an int to a varchar if I understand your schema correctly.

Comment: is 'MK'  is the value of `@StoreID` ?? if yes, then how are you comparing ` @StoreID > 1 ` (varchar to int) ?

Comment: 'MK' is not the value.  There are two tables StoreOrders and Stores.  The "@StoreID" is an int value 0-9 from StoreOrders. In table Stores I have StoreID 0-9 and StoreNames.  So when the "@StoreID" is greater then 1 in StoreOrders I need to send an e-mail with the StoreName from Stores that corresponds to the StoreID that is the same as "@StoreID"in StoreOrders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation of your schema, I'm guessing you're looking for something along these lines, which you get by joining the two tables.

```
SELECT
  @message = 'ID' + s.StoreName + '<data points from StoreOrders table, probably>'
FROM
  dbo.StoreOrders AS ord
  JOIN 
  dbo.Stores AS s
    ON
      s.StoreID = ord.StoreID
WHERE
  s.StoreID = @StoreID;
```

Comment: yes this works ... only with WHERE s.StoreID = @StoreID.

Comment: Cool. I edited the answer to reflect the comment. Thanks.